# I built my first computer a few weeks ago and it was fine, but now one of the fans is getting loud at random times. Is this bad?

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling

So a few weeks ago I built my first computer with the help of the video guide [here](https://pcpartpicker.com/guide/7MMnTW/i5-4460-radeon-r9-390-gaming-pc). I bought the Newegg combo deal listed in the guide and a few other peripherals (Razer keyboard). I didn't realize at the time I ordered it, but a few of the parts listed in the Newegg combo were different than the ones in the video guide so it was a bit more difficult to put together than I thought.

Cutting to the chase, I built it and it was running fine for the first few weeks. However, now one of the fans (it sounds/looks like the CPU fan?) is getting very loud/spinning faster when I'm not actually doing anything. For example: right now all I  am not running any games and I only have Skype, Firefox, Open Hardware Monitor, and some background processes running (Plays.tv/AMD gaming/Logitech Gaming Software/Razer Synapse) and the CPU fan is very loud.

As far as I can tell from this program I just downloaded my computer temperature isn't hot (read that it should never be above 60C). [This is my PC when the fan ISN'T loud.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35tcf.png) The fan is now quiet when I don't want it to be so I'll edit this with a picture of when the fan IS loud as soon as it happens, but for now I think the highs in the first picture are when the fan is loud. Edit: Never mind can only include 2 links so I'll leave those 2.

So should I be worried? I read I might need to change something in my BIOS, but I've never done that before so I don't want to unless it's the only solution.

Tech specs (you can also click the first link and then click the Newegg link):

```
Intel Core i5-4460 Haswell Quad-Core 3.2 GHz LGA 1150 BX80646I54460 Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4600 (Model:BX80646I54460)

ASRock H97M Pro4 LGA 1150 Intel H97 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Micro ATX Intel Motherboard (Model:H97M PRO4)

SanDisk SD8SBAT-256G-1122 Z400s 2.5" 256GB SATA III Internal Solid State Drive (Model:SD8SBAT-256G-1122)

XFX Radeon R9 390 DirectX 12 R9-390P-8256 8GB 512-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 CrossFireX Support Double Dissipation XXX OC Video Card (Model:R9-390P-8256)

G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL (Model:F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL)

Seagate Desktop HDD ST1000DM003 1TB 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive Bare Drive (Model:ST1000DM003)

Carbide Series® 88R MicroATX Mid-Tower Case (Model:CC-9011086-WW)

SeaSonic SSR-650RM 650W ATX12V / EPS12V SLI Ready CrossFire Ready 80 PLUS GOLD Certified Modular Active PFC Power Supply New 4th Gen CPU Certified Haswell Ready (Model:SSR-650RM)
```

Comment: So you are saying that, when the computer is idle, your CPU fan runs faster.  This indicates your OS is doing a task, while your system is idle, it will eventually finish and the fan won't run fast.  In other words nothing is wrong.  If you don't like the fact the Fan is high speed, get one that runs slower, or install software to control the fan and override the speed.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm more or less fine with the fan running at high speeds/being loud since I'm almost always wearing headphones, I just was/am more worried about whether or not this is bad for my computer. If what you said is true than I don't have to worry as much, so thank you :)

Comment: You don't mention how fast the fan is going.  You are not even certain it is the CPU fan, your temperatures are that low, because your fan is running though.  Anyways `1593 RPM` isn't that fast, your GPU's fan, is going the same speed.  Stock Intel fans are not known to be quite.

Comment: @Ramhound Right now it's normal and the CPU fan and GPU fan are hovering (heh, kind of a fan joke) around 1600 rpm which seems normal. Don't think I can check the speeds of the PSU fan or the fan on the case. Looks like the GPU fan goes up to 3700 rpm and the temp goes to 75C when running a high performance game (testing with The Culling) and it's the same sound that sometimes happens when I'm idle and not running a game so I guess I was wrong about it being the CPU fan.

Comment: I assume you know the difference between a fan just running and a mechanical sound a fan might make.  If the fan is just running fast, that isn't a problem, provided the temperatures are normal.  Temperatures are normal if the computer is shutting down unexpectedly or randomly.

Comment: @Ramhound From what you're saying it seems to be fine. You're probably right and I should stop worrying so much when it isn't shutting off like my last computer. Thank you for all of the help.

Comment: If you're curious about the sound, I guess you could try monitoring CPU core temperatures and fan speed (if supported) with AIDA64's System Stability Test tool and try to see if you detect a pattern there.